# Continuous contour plot

Tags: matplotlib, svm, contour, outliers, continuous

This is my code to find outliers. I would like to plot a continuous contour line over no outliers. What I'm getting is two isolated contour lines. So, I want to get only one contour (connected contour) no matter the shape. Thanks.
`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ss = [[9.0, 1.0],[1.78, 2.14],[7.36, 2.67],[5.95, 2.5 ],[2.59, 2.87],[1.76, 2.45],[1.87, 2.45],[2.15, 2.61],[1.64, 2.17],[1.35, 2.27],
      [2.16, 2.3 ],[1.48, 2.32],[1.73, 2.41],[1.73, 2.39],[3.87, 1.38],[1.81, 2.7 ],[1.92, 2.72],[1.57, 2.62],[1.59, 2.48],[3.1 , 2.56]]
ssa = np.asarray(ss)
X1 = ssa
# Learn a frontier for outlier detection with several classifiers
xx1, yy1 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10, 500), np.linspace(0, 6, 500))
model_1 = OneClassSVM(nu=0.25, gamma=0.35)
model_1.fit(X1) # clf.fit(X1)

Z1 = model_1.decision_function(np.c_[xx1.ravel(), yy1.ravel()]) # Z1 = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx1.ravel(), yy1.ravel()])
Z1 = Z1.reshape(xx1.shape)

plt.figure(1)
plt.contour(xx1, yy1, Z1, levels=[0], linewidths=2, colors='r') #'''
plt.scatter(X1[:, 0], X1[:, 1], color="black")
plt.show()
```

`
[image]

I would like to get a plot like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key is not about how to let `matplotlib` draw, is about how to let the model (`OneClassSVM`) generate what we want.

And since you are using unsupervised learning technique, sometimes we have to adjust the model's parameters to get what we think is the best (as a outside "supervisor").

So in your case, by using OneClassSVM with default kernel RBF, you can play around `nu`, `gamma`, `tol` etc:

```py
model_1 = OneClassSVM(nu=0.25, gamma=0.12)
```

[image]